# How to solve "cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem"?

Tags: laravel, sendinblue

I use WAMP on a local development environment and am trying to send mail but get the error message:

exception: "SendinBlue\Client\ApiException"

file: "\vendor\sendinblue\api-v3-sdk\lib\Api\SMTPApi.php"

line: 3986

message: "[0] cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)"

Laravel: 6.18.15

webup/laravel-sendinblue: 2.0.3

sendinblue/api-v3-sdk: 6.3.0

PHP: 7.2.25

Answer (score 0):

Sendinblue had an issue with their SMTP API on 30 May. According to their status page https://status.sendinblue.com/
Their statement on June 1, 2020 11:27AM CEST:

> [Resolved] On Saturday May 30th, 2020, at 10:48 UTC, an SSL root
>   certificate belonging to a certificate authority and used to sign one
>   of our certificate expired. Due to this some customers may have faced
>   some issues with the following application: • Automation export
>   contact was impacted on May 31th, 2020, 6:00 UTC. •
>   smtp-relay.sendinblue.com on SSL port, was impacted for some customers
>   using old browser and/or old openssl version lower than 1.1.0. We
>   fixed the issue on May 31th, 2020, 18:23 UTC, by updating the expired
>   Root certificat. We are deeply sorry for the inconvenience, and we are
>   working to improve our response to this kind of incident.

It should work now.